# Most suitable area to stay in Bali if I have conference in Kuta and mode of transport

Tags: indonesia, bali

I am travelling to Bali in July for a week in which I will be attending a conference for 2 days and the rest of the days are dedicated to sightseeing. I have two questions:

1) Which area in Bali would be most suited for my stay under the above conditions?

2) Which would be the appropriate mode of transport car rentals or local cabs?

Comment: If you have transportation, as your title says, then why don't you just use it to get to the place you're sightseeing after the conference? Eg stay in Kuta for 2 days, then go elsewhere and stay there for three rest?

Comment: The OP is asking for mode of transport, not saying they have one.